# WCF the same type exposed by two web services

Tags: c#, wcf

I have 2 webservices that expose the same type.

```
WebService1{
    public MyData Retrive(int id){...}
}
WebService2{
    public void Save(MyData x){...}
}
```

I use these 2 services like:

```
var x=client1.Retrieve(3);
client2.Save(x);
```

Problem: x is of type WebService1Client.MyData;
Save requres x of type WebService2Client.MyData;

MyData is the same type, exposed by 2 webservices. I can't put both methods in the same servie. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `MyData` in a separate class library that is then referenced by both your web services. Also reference this shared library in your clients, and when you add the service references, make sure the option to reuse types that exist is selected. Then both sides of both WCF services will be using exactly the same type.

Answer (score 1):

you can declare your class MyData in another assembly, class library, and reference that assembly from the web services and also from the client code which calls those services.

You could also consider the proper inheritance and have MyData as derived class of a base class in case this would help you, then your services only work with the base class.

in fact WCF helps a lot about this because it introduces the concept of DataContract, which you should use properly in this case.